# jQuery Sortable : cancel drag event if in same container

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am currently working on a small project that leverages jquery sortable. The desired functionality is to allow users to drag items from one list to the other but stop them from dragging and dropping in the same container the item was originally in.

In the example below I want users to be able to drag items freely from 'minor' to 'major' and vice versa, however stop them from moving items from 'minor' to 'minor' or 'major' to 'major'.

http://jsfiddle.net/r34u2pbo/

I have tried comparing the id of the current item during multiple events but have yet to find a solution.

```
$('#minor ul').sortable({
    cursor: "move",
    connectWith: "#major ul",
    beforeStop : function(){
       //parent id == original container id
    },
    stop : function(){
       //parent id == original container id
    }
});
```

Any help coming up with a solution would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After a little js debugging I was able to get the **currentContainer** object on the event.  From that I just checked if the id of the container is the same as the original and canceled the event if true.  Updated JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/r34u2pbo/1/

```
$('#minor ul').sortable({
    cursor: "move",
    connectWith: "#major ul",
    stop : function(){
        var div = $(this).data().sortable.currentContainer.element
        var id = $(div).parent('div').attr('id')
        if(id == 'minor'){
            $(this).sortable('cancel')
            alert('cannot drag within same container')
        } 
    }
});
```